# Editing WIT in VS2019 for TFS2018 and cannot save (TF237090)

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, visual-studio-addins, tfs-process-template

I use the Process Template Editor from the marketplace (Microsoft DevLabs). I load a Work Item Type from Project and (with or without changing anything) I want to save it. Then I get the error message:
`Failed to save the 'xxx' Work Item Type to the server. TF237090: Nicht vorhanden oder Zugriff verweigert.` The last sentence means in english something like not available or no permissions.

I access the server from my workstation. Both computers are in the same domain. In the AD I am only a normal user, but at the TFS I am in the group `Team Foundation-Administrators`. Inside the website I can modify everything normally. Can it be that this is a direct access to the database and the database has to be set to access external requests?

Or has someone another idea where to look?

Comment: Try importing and exporting from the commandline using WIT Admin. Also, if you're editing a specific project, you may need to grant yourself Project Administrator permissions first. Not all  configurations of TFS grant the Server Admin automatic admin permissions over projects created by other admins.

Comment: With the import I get the same error message. And I am the creator of this project and (I checked that twice) I am also in the group `project administrators`. And I also returned every single group to standard permissions, so that nothing is set to deny.